# How to count row with spesific conditions in postgresql - count daily check-in

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem to manipulate my data. I have table like this

```
customer_id   day_checkin  month_checkin  status_checkin
001                1            10        start check-in
001                2            10        check-in consecutively
001                3            10        check-in consecutively
001                4            10        check-in consecutively
001                6            10        start check-in
001                7            10        check-in consecutively
001                8            10        check-in consecutively
```

The question I want to answer is, what is the average user check-in in a row? from the example table above, this user successfully checked-in 4 days in a row (day 1 to 4). Then this user didn't check-in on day 5, which made him repeat the check-in cycle again. On the 6th day, he checked-in until the 8th day without skipping, which in this cycle he managed to check-in 3 days in a row (day 6 to 8).

I'm having trouble how to calculate it automatically from postgresql and get the average from that. I hope to get some tips from all of you for creating dashboard in Metabase. Thank you

Comment: Please add data as formatted text,  not as images. Also, the question lacks a verbal description of when several rows are considered a group. We can guess, but then you'll probably come back with "this is not what I need, in this and that case it should be different". It is tiresome to play that game.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited my problem detail. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the desired result for your example?

Comment: I want to get the average user check-in in a row, Sir. From that example, I get the average user check-in in a row is 3.5 days. Thank you in advance

Comment: From the data I have I can count from start check-in status to check-in consecutively (before start check-in status again). In that example, the output is 4 and 3

Comment: What I meant is that you should add the result you want to get for the sample data to the question. Should the result be only two numbers?